# How to fix $http GET request

Tags: angularjs

Cannot GET the end point despite passing parameter

Trying to pass an id to the end point for a GET request

**controller.js**

```
    var vid = $routeParams.vidId  //get the video id
        console.log(vid) //works
        $http({
         method:'GET',
         url:'/thread/',
         params:{vid_id:vid},

        }).then(function(success){
          console.log('success')
        }, function(error){
          console.log('error')
        })
```

**server.js**

```
app.get('/thread/:vid_id', function(req,res){
  console.log(req.params.vid_id)
})
```

I would expect seeing the `vid_id` on the server console but instead I am getting a 404 error.

```
angular.js:13531 GET http://localhost:5000/thread/?vid_id=5cb01f6b03fb0b3e6c2abf7f 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: I think you are trying to access server url which is not exists. Please re validate your URL

Comment: Maybe your url should be http://localhost:5000/thread/5cb01f6b03fb0b3e6c2abf7f ?

Comment: Still not working. Is a syntax error in the end point? I can't see any

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `params` property on `$http`, which is meant for appending query string parameters to a URL (eg. ?vid_id=123).

You instead need to dynamically set the URL that you are calling, something like this:

```
var vid = $routeParams.vidId  //get the video id
console.log(vid) //works
$http({
     method:'GET',
     url:'/thread/' + vid     // <==== HERE
})
.then(function(success){
    console.log('success')
}, function(error){
    console.log('error')
});
```

If that doesn't work, try to make your server display some text on the endpoint instead of just doing a `console.log()`:

**server.js**

```
app.get('/thread/:vid_id', function(req,res){
  res.send("test");

  console.log(req.params.vid_id)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @nevada_Scout:
I modified you suggestion to work like this:

```
$http({
     method:'GET',
     url:'/thread/' +JSON.stringify(vid),

    }).then(function(success){
      console.log(success)
    }, function(err){
      console.log(err)
    })
```

Problem solved.